# How to Convert 2D array into list and Print the list?

Tags: java

I need to convert an 2D array to list and remove the duplicates and print the values.

By using the below code, I'm unable to print the 2D array

When I tried to print it, it is printing the index value.

Even I tried using Iterator,

```
int array2D [][] = {{111,555,111,78,98},{87,54,53}};
        ArrayList<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<array2D.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<array2D[i].length;j++)
            {
                numberList.add(i, j);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(numberList);
Iterator iter = numberList.iterator();
          while (iter.hasNext()) {
             System.out.println(iter.next());
          }
```

Still it is not working.

Comment: What do you think that `numberList.add(i,j)` is supposed to do?

Comment: My guess -  it will add the rows and columns to the array

Comment: What do you mean "My guess"? Didn't you write this program? You must have had some intention when you wrote that instruction. Anyway, `list.add(x,y)` puts the value `y` in the `x` position an a list. So if `x` is 6 and `y` is 20, the 7th element in the list will be 20.

Answer (score 0):

> When I tried to print it, it printing the index value.

It is printing the index value because you added the indexes instead of actual value. You should add the actual value of an array by index `i` and `j` like:

```
 numberList.add(array2D[i][j]);
```

If you want to remove duplicates you could use `Set` instead of `ArrayList`:

```
Set<Integer> numberList = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Comment: Using a `HashSet` will change the order of the elements. When the task says "moving to a list", rather than "moving to a collection", it implies that the order is important, as that's the basic premise of a list.